# "Error decompressing python39.dll" when executing docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I had some issues executing docker-compose commands lately. In my observation, this happens after my Docker installation was upgraded. And before it was upgraded, I had no issues executing it. I am using Visual Studio and Windows 10. Docker version is: `Docker` `version 20.10.10`, `build b485636`

Would greatly appreciate anyone's help. Here is the error:

```
[20120] Error -5 from inflate: (null)   
[20120] Error decompressing python39.dll
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: After some initial searching, I came across about Docker Compose v2 and it states that:

> **Compose V2 and the new docker compose command**
> *Important*
>
> The new Compose V2, which supports the compose command as part of the
> Docker CLI, is now available.
>
> Compose V2 integrates compose functions into the Docker platform,
> continuing to support most of the previous docker-compose features and
> flags. You can test the Compose V2 by simply replacing the dash (-)
> with a space, and by running docker compose, instead of
> docker-compose.
>
> Starting with Docker Desktop 3.4.0, you can run Compose V2 commands
> without modifying your invocations, by enabling the drop-in
> replacement of the previous docker-compose with the new command. See
> the section Installing Compose V2 for detailed instructions how to
> enable the drop-in replacement.

So yeah, I tried executing using "docker compose" without the dash (-) in between docker and compose and it works..